# How to do large matrix decomposition with GPU in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to do a matrix decomposition (or tucker decomposition on a tensor) in Tensorflow with GPU. I have tensorflow-gpu, my NVidia GPU has 4GB RAM. My problem is that my input matrix is huge, millions of rows and millions of columns and the size of the matrix is more than 5GB in memory. So each time Tensorflow gives me an out of memory (OOM) error. (If I turn off GPU, the whole process can run successfully in CPU using system RAM. Of course, the speed is slow.)

I did some research on Tensorflow and on NVidia CUDA lib. CUDA seems has a "unified memory" mechanism so the system RAM and GPU RAM share one address book. Yet no further details found.

I wonder if Tensorflow supports some memory sharing mechanism such that I can generate input in system RAM? (Since I want to use GPU to accelerate the calculations) And GPU can do the calculation piece by piece.

Comment: Can this decomposition be split into smaller fragments manually? That’s your best bet. Shared memory architectures usually starve the GPU and you lose a lot of the speed advantage.

Comment: Thank you for your cut-to-the-point comments, Kuba. I haven't found any easy/efficient ways to do it. One reason is I didn't find an easy way to split this SVD-similar job. Secondly, I am not sure it's worth it considering the difference of different RAM's bandwidth.